# greenlock-express: TypeError: greenlock.app is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, greenlock

I am trying to run my Express.js with greenlock-express using this example:

https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/production.js

But I am getting these errors:

```
[:80] Handling ACME challenges and redirecting to http2 (spdy/h2)
[:443] Serving http2 (spdy/h2)

[error] [greenlock.app] Your HTTP handler had an uncaught error:

TypeError: greenlock.app is not a function
    at //node_modules/greenlock-express/index.js:64:23
```

Does anyone know why the example fails, and how I should fix it?

Comment: Hi Tayyab. Can you elabore a bit more please?

Comment: Try to run my express js with greenlock-express using example: https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/production.js

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Your code should be in the question. When the link breaks, your question is useless. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question, to include the info in your comment. When asked for clarification, please use the "edit" link below your post to update the question. That way, we have all the information in the question itself, which makes it easier for people to answer. Also, please tell us what you've tried to solve this yourself (again, in the question, not in comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of greenlock and your problem is one of two things:

## `app` must be a function

In your greenlock config you need to define `app` as `function (req, res) { ... }`

For example:

```
greenlock.create({
  ...
, app: function (req, res) {
    require('./my-express-app.js')(req, res);
  }
})
```

## express app must be exported

```
var app = express();
...
module.exports = app;
```

## watch (and follow) the video(s)

If you follow this verbatim you will have a working config and you will be able to change it from there:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8vaR4CEZ5s&list=PLZaEVINf2Bq_lrS-OOzTUJB4q3HxarlXk

## error message

I tried to make the error message pretty clear:

```
TypeError: greenlock.app is not a function
    at //node_modules/greenlock-express/index.js:64:23
```

It makes sense to me, of course, but obviously not to you - otherwise we wouldn't be here right now. :)

Do you have any suggestions as to how I could make it better?